How to use templ in conjunction with the Echo framework?
I'm planning use templ library like this github.com/a-h/templ v0.2.707
but there is problem where rendering html
first will show you my code written so far:
go.mod

module cozy

go 1.21.6

require (
    github.com/a-h/templ v0.2.707
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.12.0
)

require (
    github.com/golang-jwt/jwt v3.2.2+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/labstack/gommon v0.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.13 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.20 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/fasttemplate v1.2.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.22.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.24.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/time v0.5.0 // indirect
)


app/util/render.go

package util

import (
    "github.com/a-h/templ"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func Render(ctx echo.Context, statusCode int, t templ.Component) error {
    ctx.Response().Writer.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    ctx.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderContentType, echo.MIMETextHTML)
    return t.Render(ctx.Request().Context(), ctx.Response().Writer)
}


app/view/temp.templ

package view

templ Temp() {
    <div>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
}


app/controller/mainController.go
package web

import (
    "cozy/app/util"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type MainController struct {
}

func NewMainController() MainController {
    return MainController{}
}

func (controller MainController) MainPage(c echo.Context) error {
    return util.Render(c, 200, layout.Temp())
}


In controller tried rendering templ function but got error like this

im do find example code and tried followed
I think templ extension not supported in ide or golang, config something wrong
because this example code is working.
I don't know what is wrong and what i do can you help

Was the generation step done? As in the example in the quick start guide. This generates a go file from a templ file.

What is layout.Temp() intended to do in mainController.go? There's nothing called layout defined in that code.
